# Why the case labels must be constant expression if we are providing variables as a case labels the compiler will raise compilation error

Tags: java, switch-statement

***Here is the code in which constant variable are present***
**Why the case labels must be constant expression if we are providing variables as a case labels the compiler will raise compilation error**

```
 Class Test
    {
    public static void main(String[] args )
        {
            int a =10 ,b=20 ,c=30 ; //Here i give constant value
            switch(a){

            case a : System.out.println("10");
                    break;
            case b : System.out.println("20");
                    break;
            case c : System.out.println("30");
                    break;
            default : System.out.println("Default Statement ");
                    }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle certification (OCA) training document :

**Legal Expressions for switch and case**

*The general form of the switch statement is*

```
switch (expression) {
  case constant1: code block
  case constant2: code block
  default: code block
}
```

*A case constant must evaluate to the same type that the switch expression can use, with one additional—and big—constraint: the case constant must be a compile-time constant! Since the case argument has to be resolved at compile time, you can use only a constant or final variable that is immediately initialized with a literal value. It is not enough to be final; it must be a compile time constant.*

Example of what is working and what is not :

```
final int a = 1;
final int b;
b = 2;
int x = 0;
switch (x) {
  case a: // ok
  case b: // compiler error
}
```

In your case, use :

```
final int a=10, b=20, c=30;
```

Comment: Class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args )
 {
  final int a =10 ,b=20 ,c=30;
  switch(a){
  
  case a : System.out.println("10");
    break;
  case b : System.out.println("20");
    break;
  case c : System.out.println("30");
    break;
  default : System.out.println("Default Statement ");
    }
 }


}

Comment: I copy-pasted your comment code in the [compilejava.net](https://www.compilejava.net/) online java compiler. The compilation result is `Successfully compiled /tmp/java_PTfJ0q/Test.java <-- main method` and the execution result is `10`. Your question does not say which java version you are using. I assumed Java 7 or 8. Under these versions, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In java Constant means whose value should not change again.

So if you put **final** keyword before your variables then those will become constant for java and Compiler wont give error for that.

```
final  int  a =10 ,b=20 ,c=30 ; //Here i give constant value
```